# Xcode: ld: symbol(s) not found but both classes are there

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the following message error:

```
".objc_class_name_ClassA", referenced from:
literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CBLookupItemBook in ClassB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

But both classA and classB are in the target Compile Sources.

I've cleaned, deleted the build folder, and restarted Xcode.
Still the same issue.

Comment: Are ClassA and ClassB the real names of the classes?

Comment: No I've replaced the real names with ClassA and ClassB. Why ?

Comment: I'm wondering whether ClassA or ClassB might be part of an external framework that isn't linked.

Comment: @Scott Forbes No they are classes of the app. I've written them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a misspelling in the class name... not sure why the compiler didn't complain about it

Answer (score 1):

Checked that the files containing the classes are part of the target you are trying to compile. View > Utilities > Show File Inspector, Target Membership in the right inspector panel.

Comment: I'm using xCode 3. I'm control-clicking on the specific file to get the info panel and then the "Targets" tab. They are already in the correct targets.

Comment: Thanks for that, that worked for me! Still very confused as to how that happened in the first place though, as I thought this was done automatically by Xcode when you added new files to the project.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 4, if you're having this issue, you may want to click on your project -> target -> build phases -> compile sources. Verify that the missing class is actually being compiled. If it isn't, press the plus button at the end of the list and add it. I had this problem when I trashed a class (because it was based off of a UIViewController but I wanted to base it off of a UITableViewController) and then added another class with the same name. It seemed Xcode was tripped up by that and didn't automatically add the class to be compiled.